# Setting the Destination to iOS Device in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, device

Yet, I have Xcode 4.2 open and my source code.

In the top left scheme dropdown, I have the scheme set but on the right hand side of that dropdown, its got my device set there. 
I don't want my device set there because I'm not testing anymore.
I want to build/archive for distribution.

I want to see iOS Device in that target but I don't see it there.

Any idea how I can get iOS Device to be listed in that destination dropdown?

Currently, it has ipad and iPhone simulators and my own iPhone name.

Answer (score 1):

Just select your iPhone name and go to `Product -> Archive`.

Or unplug all your iOS devices and then there will be shown `iOS Device` label.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that as soon as I posted this but couldn't repost an answer within 8 hours

Comment: I wasted an hour trying to figure out how to get iOS device to display on scheme destination. I always had my iphone connected to my mac, and your comment finally solved my problem - as soon as i removed the iphone I got the scheme destination i wanted (iOS device).. makes you wonder what the logic behind not always displaying iOS Device is..